# Test using JMeter without increasing number of users

Tags: jmeter

I want to test web service with this configurartion: 3 users per second within 1 hour. I understand that classic scenario is increasing number of users every n second. But I need keep stable number of users, how to do it?

Comment: I think Jmeter 5.5 with Open Thread Model can solve this https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Open_Model_Thread_Group . Or you can check the plugin Arrival Thread Group. https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/ArrivalsThreadGroup/

Answer (score 1):

We could achieve this using both the built-in Thread Group in JMeter, as well as using a custom Thread Group from a popular JMeter plugin.

**For a built-in method:**
You can use configuration from a normal Thread Group to run 3 threads consistently for an hour.

1. Set "Number of Threads" to 3
2. Set "Ramp-up Period" to 0 to ensure we have a constant three users at all times
3. Check the "Specify Thread lifetime" option
4. Enter 3600 into the "Duration" option to specify an hour

**For a third-party plugin method:**
This will achieve the same result, but with some more control and visualization.

1. Download and install the [Custom Thread Groups plugin](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/ConcurrencyThreadGroup/)
2. Add a "Concurrency Thread Group" to your plan
3. Set "Target Concurrency" to 3 to define your user count
4. Set "Hold Target Rate Time" to 60 to run for an hour

If you'd like to tweak your settings further, the included graphical representation in the third-party plugin method is a great resource.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

It's easily configurable, just don't specify any ramp-up period in the [Thread Group](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Thread_Group):

[image]

If your "3 users per second" means "3 requests per second" depending on your endpoint response time you might need either more users or to limit JMeter's throughput to 3 requests per second using i.e. [Constant Throughput Timer](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-throughput) as the above Thread Group setup will give you 3 requests per second only if your application response time is 1 second sharp. If it will be 2 seconds you will have 1.5 requests per second, if it will be 500 milliseconds you will have 6 requests per second, etc.